# Edit existing contact with RingCentral API

Tags: ringcentral

I want to develop application in Python where it can bulk edit contacts in address book with all its related details. I need a backend RC API to do that task for me and will be called from my applicatio.

Comment: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/External-Contacts/updateContact.  https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-python.  Here are two references to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update contact API which updates personal contact information by contact ID(s)

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/External-Contacts/updateContact

Also can use updateFavoriteContactList which updates the list of favorite contacts of the current extension. Favorite contacts include both company contacts (extensions) and personal contacts:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/External-Contacts/updateFavoriteContactList